# Findstr:Batch to find String (all lines) between two fixed characters

Tags: windows, string, batch-file, dos

I am totally new to DOS. Infact I am a Java guy. I need to do some string search operations but unfortunately string search & file search operation in java is considerably slow. And its very fast in OS.
So here is my problem. I need to search all files with fixed extension (.sp) for strings (all lines) between 2 fixed characters. They are ';' & ';'
Here is the content of one of .sp file.
File:- Tons.sp

```
line 1: Skipcheck;
line 2: [Scenario:'Actual']=STET;
line 3: ['WFS':'Actual','Scenario':'Actual','Measure':'Units']=N:
line 4: IF( SUBST( !Measure, 1, 1) @= '8'
line 5: ,
line 6:     ['Amount']
line 7: ,
line 8:    STET
line 9: );
line10: 
line11: ['Tons'] = N:
line12: DB('Volume Master',!Version,!Year,!Plant,'GL_CODE_0004',!Period,!Measure) ;
line13: 
line14: ['Group1_Volume'] = N:
line15: IF ( ELISANC( 'Plant', 'Group1' , !Plant )=1 
line16:     , ['Take_This']
line17:    , CONTINUE
line18: );
line19: 
line20: ['Tons Trend']=N:
line21: IF( DB('Monthly_Trend', !Period, 'Tons_Trend_Factor') > 0
line22: , 'Current_Tons' * DB('Volume Master',!Version,!Year,!Plant,'GL_CODE_TonsProduced',!Period,!Measure) 
line23: , CONTINUE
line24: );
```

*Please Note: line numbers are just for indication.*

**Problem 1:** Now I need to find the string (all lines) that lie between ';' & ';' that contains string "DB('Volume Master'"
ie.: The findstring will be something like this:-

```
FINDSTR /n "=*DB('Volume Master'*;" *.sp
```

The result of above command should be line 10 to 12  & line 19 to 24

```
line10: 
line11: ['Tons'] = N:
line12: DB('Volume Master',!Version,!Year,!Plant,'GL_CODE_0004',!Period,!Measure) ;
```

&

```
line19: 
line20: ['Tons Trend']=N:
line21: IF( DB('Monthly_Trend', !Period, 'Tons_Trend_Factor') > 0
line22: , 'Current_Tons' * DB('Volume Master',!Version,!Year,!Plant,'GL_CODE_TonsProduced',!Period,!Measure) 
line23: , CONTINUE
line24: );
```

**Problem 2:** The output of this:-

```
FINDSTR /n "=*DB('Volume Master'*'GL_CODE_TonsProduced'*;" *.sp
```

should be:-

```
line19: 
line20: ['Tons Trend']=N:
line21: IF( DB('Monthly_Trend', !Period, 'Tons_Trend_Factor') > 0
line22: , 'Current_Tons' * DB('Volume Master',!Version,!Year,!Plant,'GL_CODE_TonsProduced',!Period,!Measure) 
line23: , CONTINUE
line24: );
```

Please help.

Thanks
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"

SET "target=DB('Volume Master'"
SET "target=DB('Volume Master'.*'GL_CODE_TonsProduced'"
SET "blockend=;"
DEL  "%destdir%\res*" 2>nul
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q24237940.txt) DO (
 >>"%destdir%\res.tmp" ECHO(%%a
 ECHO(%%a|FINDSTR /l /c:"%blockend%">NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  FINDSTR /r /c:"%target%" "%destdir%\res.tmp" >NUL
  IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 TYPE "%destdir%\res.tmp" >>"%destdir%\res.txt"
  DEL "%destdir%\res.tmp" /F /Q
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q24237940.txt` containing your data for my testing.

I've used variables for convenience; `destdir` containing the destination directory for the resultant file, `target` for the target string which must occur within the block and `blockend` for the string that indicates end-of-block.

Note that I've left **both** targets in the code, the  later one will be used. `findstr` finds on a line-by-line basis, so `DB...` and `GL_CODE...` must occur on the same line in this example. Since findstr has an attempt at using regular expressions, `.*` means `any number of any character` - where the characer set does not include newline.

In essence, create `res.tmp` containing a block at a time, and when end-of-block is found, detect whether that tempfile contains the magic string; append it to `res.txt` if it does.